# What type of grammar is used to parse Lua?

Tags: parsing, lua, grammar

I recently met the concept of LR, LL etc. Which category is Lua? Are there, or, can there be implementations that differ from the official code in this aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LR, LL and so on are algorithms which attempt to find a parser for a given grammar. This is not possible for every grammar, and you can categorize on the basis of that possibility. But you have to be aware of the difference between a *language* and a *grammar*.

It might be possible to create an LR(*k*) parser for a given *grammar*, for some specific value of *k*. If so, the *grammar* is LR(*k*). Note that an LR(*k*) grammar is also an LR(*k*+1) grammar, and that an LL(*k*) grammar is also LR(*k*). So these are not categories in the sense that every grammar is in exactly one category.

Any *language* can be recognised by many different *grammars*. (In fact, an unlimited number). These grammars can be arbitrarily complex. You can always write a grammar for a given language which is not even context-free. We say that a *language* is <*X*> if there exists a grammar for that language which is <*X*>. But the fact that a specific grammar for that language is *not* <*X*> says nothing.

One interesting theorem demonstrates that if there is an LR(*k*) grammar for any language, then it is possible to derive an LR(1) grammar for that language. So while the *k* parameter is useful for describing grammars, languages can only be LR(0) or LR(1). This is not true of LL(*k*) languages, though.

Lua as a language is basically LR(1) and LL(2). The [grammar is part of the reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9), except that the published grammar doesn't specify operator precedences or a few rules having to do with newlines. The actual parser is a hand-written recursive-descent parser (at least, the last time I looked) with a couple of small deviations in order to handle operator precedence and the minor deviations from LL(1). However, there exist LALR(1) parsers for Lua as well.

Comment: Can't cast a vote yet, but you more than answered my question. Thanks a lot!